# How to export openbox key bindings to text file?

Tags: linux, desktop-customization, openbox

There is tool `obkey` that allows for convenient editing and browsing Openbox keybindings. Is there a way to export these mapping to a plain text file? Perhaps there exist script that parses Openbox settings file `rc.xml` and extracts relevant info?

Answer (score 0):

There is a script `al-kb-pipemenu` included in ArchLabs distribution that display keybindings in the text window.